# Prevent perl from printing a newline

Tags: perl, command-line

I have this simple command:

```
printf TEST | perl -nle 'print lc'
```

Which prints:

```
test
​
```

I want:

```
test
```

...without the newline. I tried perl's `printf` but that removes *all* newlines, and I'd like to keep existing one's in place. Plus, that wouldn't work for my second example that doesn't even use `print` in it:

```
printf "BOB'S BIG BOY" | perl -ple 's/([^\s.,-]+)/\u\L$1/g'
```

Which prints:

```
Bob's Big Boy
​
```

...with that annoying newline as well. I'm hoping for a magical switch like --no-newline but I'm guessing it's something more involved.

EDIT: I've changed my use of `echo` in the examples to `printf` to clarify the problem. A few commenters were correct in stating that my problem wouldn't actually be fixed as it was written.

Comment: Simply remove the `-l` switch, see `perldoc perlrun`

Comment: Wow, easier than I hoped for. Create an answer for me!

Comment: It's odd that it seems to convert `"TEST\n"` to `"test"`. I think you need to copy/paste from the console.

Comment: @sudopeople: Stack Overflow posts are meant to benefit anyone with a similar problem. If you have a real solution here then please identify it, because, as `@hobbs` describes in his comment, removing the `-l` option doesn't fix the problem as you have stated it.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's not my code, so yeah, *I* was using `-l` without knowing what it does. It's flattering that you are willing to take time out of your life to contribute in such a meaningless way.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of your sarcasm is. You made a mistake (which is nothing to be ashamed of; we all do), I pointed it out, and somehow I'm the bad guy.

Comment: You're right, pointing out that I made a mistake in the code I didn't write while not contributing in any way toward solving the mistake is very constructive - my mistake, again. You're an Internet hero.

Comment: Ok, here's some constructive advice. Next time you encounter a similar problem, read the documentation for the options you're using. You might be able to solve the problem yourself more quickly than waiting for someone else to post an answer. I also advise toning down the sarcasm (unless, of course, it's "constructive"). Incidentally, if you want me to see a comment, you should include my name preceded by an `@` character; I didn't do so on my comments here because you're automatically notified for comments on your own post.

Comment: I did RTFM as stated; it's huge. `man perl` at 2011 words makes no mention of switches. Then I ran `perldoc perlrun` @ 7526 words. `-l` is described with 121; terms that I don't have a strong knowledge of, including: `chomp`, *input record separator*, & `octnum`. Next time, I'll become an expert in perl for a one-liner. Thanks for the protip on the `@` - I opted not to use it again in my subsequent replies since I know you can't resist returning to demonstrate your people skills. My question here was answered in < 120 seconds, FYI. Maybe if you'd STFU, you too could save yourself some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to remove the `-l` switch, see [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

```
-l[octnum]
    enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate
    effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record
    separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output
    record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print
    statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is
    omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/.
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I never knew about `perldoc perlrun` and got very little from `man perl`.

Comment: @sudopeople: You should investigate [`perldoc.perl.org`](http://perldoc.perl.org/). I have edited sputnick's answer to add a link to the relevant page

Comment: `-l` removes newlines from input as well as adding them to output. `echo TEST | perl -ne 'print lc'` should work the same with and without `-l`, unless echo and perl disagree about newline convention.

Comment: @sudopeople `perldoc` is an excellent tool, and it isn't limited to just documenting command line flags. Special variables are documented in `perlvar`, syntax in `perlsyn`, operators in `perlop`, and many more. You can view the documentation for built-in functions using `perldoc -f funcname`, e.g. `perldoc -f sort`, and can see the documentation for installed modules using `perldoc Module::Name`, e.g. `perldoc LWP::UserAgent`.

Comment: @hobbs: I thought as you did for a while, but
the problem is that the output record separator applies to *every* output, whereas `chomp`ing the input text makes a difference only if the input record is terminated with the input record separator. So, with `-l` in effect, both `"test"` and `"test\n"` will be read as `"test"`, which will then be output as `"test\n"`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: *"You may know a man's heart by his choice of `perldoc` example"*

Comment: @Borodin no argument there, but that doesn't get you two newlines :)

Comment: @hobbs: Sure, but is the OP getting `"test\n\n"`? My guess from his markdown was that he was seeing one when he expected none, but I agree that an extra highlighted line doesn't say much

Comment: @sudopeople: Please contribute to this analysis. What output are you *actually* seeing?

Comment: Removing the `-l` is not going to make a difference in the output in the provided example

Comment: @sudopeople, `man perlrun` would have given you the same information

Comment: For a good overview of the documentation that comes with Perl, try `perldoc perltoc` (or `man perltoc`).

Comment: Thanks @hobbs, I changed the example to use `printf` - you're absolutely correct in that `echo` wouldn't produce the results I described.